# (Kubernetes HPA) Scaling up pods got connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I have some amount of traffic that can boost the cpu usage up to 180%. I tried using a single pod which works fine but the response was extremely slow. When I configured my HPA to cpu=80%, min=1 and max={2 or more} I hit connection refused when HPA was creating more pods. I tried put a large value to min (ie. min = 3) the connection refused relief but there will be too many idle pods when traffic is low. Is there any way to stop putting pod online until it is completely started?

Comment: Sounds like more going on with Kubernetes.  Can you find the Kubernetes logs and add more details to this question?  There should be some indication of error starting pods when scaling beyond 1 pod.  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/system-logs/

Answer (score 1):

> I hit connection refused when HPA was creating more pods

Kubernetes uses the readinessProbe, to determine whether to redirect clients to some pods. If the readinessProbe for a Pod is not successful, then Service whose selectors could have matched that Pod would not take it under consideration.

If there is no readinessProbe defined, or if it was misconfigured, Pods that are still starting up may end up serving client requests. Connection refused could suggest there was no process listening yet for incoming connections.

Please share your deployment/statefulset/..., if you need further assistance setting this up.